# How to run a dependency exe installer during setup process

Tags: node.js, electron, nsis, libreoffice

I need to integrate [Libre Office portable installer](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/portable-versions/) inside my electron NSIS setup and run it during the electron app installation process. I've followed thi suggestion and now I have this custom NSIS script that will call the portable instaler.

```
!macro customInstall
    Exec '$INSTDIR/dependencies/LibreOfficePortable.exe -Path $INSTDIR'
!macroEnd
```

I'm able to build the NSIS setup for my electron app but when I run it and it will call the custom nsis script, Libre Office will fail to install because it will ask me to close all the instances of Libre Office that are opened. Is there a way to let it installed correctly?

I will need it to run docx to pdf conversion using [carbone library](https://github.com/carboneio/carbone) for node.js

Thank you.

Comment: If you are asking about the LibreOffice installer then you need to ask them or the portableapps guys for support, there might be a switch you can pass to their installer...

Answer (score 1):

From [LibreOffice Portable Support](https://portableapps.com/support/libreoffice_portable):

> **LibreOffice Portable don't start and insists another version is running:**
> Open the following file in a text editor (like notepad): LibreOfficePortable\App\AppInfo\Launcher\LibreOfficePortable.ini At the bottom of the first section "[Launch]" add the following line: SingleAppInstance=false save and close the file and the program will load.

I assume this means you have to re-compile the portable Libre Office yourself but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: In our systems we run only MS Office, so the portable choice is only to use it for pdf conversion using carbone library that need the Libre Office server to do the job. I will try your suggestion anyway. Thank you